# How can I fix OpenSSL error when importing a package in a Python notebook in ArcGIS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geemap

I receive the following error when trying to import a specific package (`geemap`) into a python notebook:

```
Exception: OpenSSL 3.0's legacy provider failed to load. This is a fatal error by default, but cryptography supports running without legacy algorithms by setting the environment variable CRYPTOGRAPHY_OPENSSL_NO_LEGACY. If you did not expect this error, you have likely made a mistake with your OpenSSL configuration.
```

I confirmed that the package is installed and I am not having issues with importing other packages. Any suggestions on how to address this and what the source of the issue is? Thank you!

I tried setting the environment variable using: `os.environ[CRYPTOGRAPHY_OPENSSL_NO_LEGACY] ="1"`, but received a `NameError`.

Comment: The `NameError` occurs most likely because you don't use quotation marks around `CRYPTOGRAPHY_OPENSSL_NO_LEGACY`. Try: `os.environ["CRYPTOGRAPHY_OPENSSL_NO_LEGACY"] = "1"`. However, I don't know why you get the first exception. Hope someone else can help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand why I received that error, the solution ended up being very simple. I restarted ArcGIS and corrected the typo:

```
import os
os.environ["CRYPTOGRAPHY_OPENSSL_NO_LEGACY"] ="yes"
import geemap
```

That was it.